# How can I tell Axis WSDL2Java to take WSDLs from a JAR?

Tags: java, wsdl, classpath, axis, wsdl2java

I have a maven project in which I am using the Codehaus Axis Tools plugin to run WSDL2Java.

Unfortunately, I do not have direct control of my WSDLs - they are provided to me in a JAR which is in my Maven repository. My project has a Maven dependency on the WSDL JAR, hence the WSDL files are resources in my class path.

Is it possible to configure WSDL2Java to pick up WSDL files from inside a JAR? Or more specifically, from resources the class path?

Looking at the documentation at Codehaus (http://mojo.codehaus.org/axistools-maven-plugin/wsdl2java-mojo.html), I see that there are two configuration parameters `sourceDependecies` and `wsdlFiles` that I may be able to use - but there is not much information about how to use them.

I have tried the following

```
<sourceDependencies>
  <sourceDependency>
    <groupId>myGroupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>myArtifactId</artifactId>
    <version>myVersion</version>
  </sourceDependency>
</sourceDependecies>
<wsdlFiles>
  <wsdlFile>myFile.wsdl</wsdlFile>
</wsdlFiles>
```

and

```
<sourceDependencies>
  <sourceDependency>
    <groupId>myGroupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>myArtifactId</artifactId>
    <version>myVersion</version>
    <file>myFile.wsdl</file>
  </sourceDependency>
</sourceDependecies>
```

where `myFile.wsdl` is a resource in the JAR identified by the dependency, inside the configuration of the plugin, but to no avail.

Since `<configuration>` is not strongly-typed in Maven, it is really hard to figure out what may or may not be going on.

**Update**: I don't necessarily need to use Axis. I could just as well use some other framework's WSDL-to-Java generation tool to create my stubs, if it supports reading WSDL files as resources on the classpath. Any recommendations?

Comment: Would unzipping your jar be an option? You could create some ant task for that.

Comment: I could unzip the JAR, but it seems a bit convoluted. The JAR containing the WSDLs also contains classes and XSDs that are a dependency to my project anyway, hence it is in the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

you can try it like this：

```
<sourceDependencies>
  <sourceDependency>
    yourGroupId:yourArtifactId:yourVersion:yourFile.wsdl
  </sourceDependency>
</sourceDependecies>
```

How terrible it is!